# replace special chars to space and create list

Tags: python

using Python, I'm trying to replace the special chars in the following text:

```
"The# dog.is.yelling$at!Me to"
```

to spaces so that afterwards I would get the list:

```
['The','dog','is','yelling','at','me']
```

How do I do that in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split("[#$!.\s]+", "The# dog.is.yelling$at!Me to" )
['The', 'dog', 'is', 'yelling', 'at', 'Me', 'to']
```

Or to split by any non alpha-numeric sequence of chars, as pointed @thg435:

```
>>> re.split("\W+", "The# dog.is.yelling$at!Me to" )
```

Comment: simply `re.split(r'\W+')`